# Can't access folders after username change

Tags: nautilus, users, home-directory

I created a new user so I could change my primary account's username.

First, I did:

```
sudo usermod -l newUsername oldUsername
```

Then:

```
sudo usermod -d /home/newHomeDir -m newUsername
```

Logged out, then logged in as my primary user. Opened terminal, it shows my new username. Try to double click Documents, Music, Pictures, Videos, or Downloads in Nautilus and it tells me:

```
"Could not find '/home/<oldUsername>/Documents'"
```

What do I do?

**Edit** I reversed the commands to get my old username back. Would still like to know how to do this the correct way so I don't break things again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't break anything, it's just that some applications still look up your old username home path, e.g. /home/OLDUSERNAME. You can try to create a symlink between your new /home/username and your old /home/username to solve issues with applications that still use the old username. This should do it:

```
sudo ln -s /home/NEWUSERNAME /home/OLDUSERNAME
```

(replace NEWUSERNAME and OLDUSERNAME with the new/old username)

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a try later this afternoon and come back to give you a checkmark. :-)